# How to change Laravel 5.4 notifications Via Manual

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How to set via in controller

If one user want notification on mail and second user not want to notification in mail
So how to setup that one user notification send on mail and second user notification not send on mail

```
$newinvoice = New NewInvoice('create a new invoice',$invoice->id);
$newinvoice->via(['database','broadcast','mail']);
Notification::send($sendToUser, $newinvoice);
```

when I run this code give me error

```
InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90: Driver [1] not supported.
```

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the channel as another argument to your notifications constructor

```
$newinvoice = New NewInvoice('create a new invoice',$invoice->id, 'mail');
```

You can also provide an array of channels

```
$newinvoice = New NewInvoice('create a new invoice',$invoice->id, ['mail', 'broadcast']);
```

Create a property in your notifiable class

```
protected $_channel = null;
```

Your constructor can save the channels to this property

```
public function __construct($description, $invoiceId, $notificationChannel)
{
    $this->_channel = $notificationChannel;
}
```

Your via() method could do things like this

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    if (!$this->_channel)
    {
        throw new \Exception('Sending a message failed. No channel provided.');
    }
    return is_array($this->_channel) ? $this->_channel : [$this->_channel];
}
```